# Stream from string in D

Tags: d

Is there a way to use `string` as `InputStream`?

Assuming I've downloaded text data from the network:

```
string str = to!string(std.net.curl.get("www.someurl.com/data.txt"));
```

And now I want to parse it using `read()`-family functions for scanning different types.

In plain C there is a `sscanf` function. In C++ we have `std::stringstream`. 
So how to get similar functionality in D?

Comment: doesn't std.net.curl have an input stream variant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the two likely candidates are [std.conv.parse](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.parse) and [std.format.formattedRead](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_format.html#.formattedRead).

`parse` will allow you to parse a string as a variety of types by making multiple calls to it. It takes the string by `ref` and consumes as much of the string as it can when converting it to requested type. It works particularly well when what you want to do is consume the string over a series of calls rather than converting it all at once. e.g.

```
import std.array;
import std.conv;
import std.math;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    auto str = "10 12.22 3.14159 22";
    auto a = parse!int(str);
    assert(a == 10);
    assert(str == " 12.22 3.14159 22");

    str = str.stripLeft();
    assert(str == "12.22 3.14159 22");

    auto b = parse!double(str);
    assert(approxEqual(b, 12.22));
    assert(str == " 3.14159 22");

    str = str.stripLeft();
    assert(str == "3.14159 22");

    auto c = parse!long(str);
    assert(c == 3);
    assert(str == ".14159 22");

    str = str.stripLeft();
    assert(str == ".14159 22");

    auto d = parse!float(str);
    assert(approxEqual(d, 0.14159));
    assert(str == " 22");

    str = str.stripLeft();
    assert(str == "22");

    auto e = parse!int(str);
    assert(e == 22);
    assert(str.empty);
}
```

`formattedRead` on the other hand is closer to `sscanf`. You have to give it a format string, and it'll return how many elements it read. Similar to `parse`, it'll consume the string as it reads it, but it consumes according to the format string rather than trying to consume as much of the string as it can to convert into the one, request type. Unlike `sscanf` however, `formattedRead` is type safe and is aware of the types of the variables being passed to it. So, you can use `%s` with it to convert to the types of the given variables rather than having to give flags specific to the types of the variables used (though you can still use more specific flags if you want to - just like with `writefln`). e.g.

```
import std.array;
import std.format;
import std.math;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    auto str = "10 12.22 3.14159 22";
    int a;
    double b;
    long c;
    auto numRead1 = formattedRead(str, "%s %s %s", &a, &b, &c);
    assert(numRead1 == 3);
    assert(a == 10);
    assert(approxEqual(b, 12.22));
    assert(c == 3);
    assert(str == ".14159 22");

    float d;
    int e;
    auto numRead2 = formattedRead(str, "%s %s", &d, &e);
    assert(numRead2 == 2);
    assert(approxEqual(d, 0.14159));
    assert(e == 22);
    assert(str.empty);
}
```

Other alternatives would be to simply take advantage of the fact that strings are ranges and use the various range-based functions in Phobos to consume the string in whatever manner fits what you're doing. For instance, if you knew that you're string was made up purely of integers separated by whitespace, you could convert them to a range of `int`s lazily by doing

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;
import std.conv;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    auto str = "42 22 9 77 46 2 1 0 99";
    auto range = std.array.splitter(str).map!(a => to!int(a))();
    assert(equal(range, [42, 22, 9, 77, 46, 2, 1, 0, 99]));
}
```

And if you wanted an array instead of a lazy range, you could simply call `std.array.array` on the range.

You can do a *lot* with the various range-based functions (the main ones being in [std.range](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html) and [std.algorithm](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html)), but if you're converting a string's contents to something else, they'll tend to work better if the contents are uniform, since you can just convert the whole string at once that way, but you could use functions like [`find`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#find) and [`until`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#until) to pick the string apart and convert it in pieces if you need to convert different parts of the string differently. You could also use `splitter` to split the string on whitespace and then convert each piece according to where it was in the string, but at that point, you probably might as well just use `parse` or `formattedRead`. You do have quite a lot of options though.

If you're not particularly familiar with ranges, then I'd advise reading http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ranges.html as it's the best tutorial that we have on them at the moment.